# jenkins node ssh-connection fails

Tags: jenkins, ssh

I try to connect a VM(Windows 10) as a node in jenkins with ssh. 
But after some lines occurs the following error:

```
[10/11/18 11:45:10] [SSH] Starting agent process: cd "C:\jenkins" && java  -jar remoting.jar -workDir C:\jenkins
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>Okt 11, 2018 11:45:11 AM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager initializeWorkDir
INFORMATION: Using C:\jenkins\remoting as a remoting work directory
Both error and output logs will be printed to C:\jenkins\remoting
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>ERROR: Connection terminated
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.ObjectInputStreamEx.<init>(ObjectInputStreamEx.java:49)
    at hudson.remoting.Command.readFrom(Command.java:140)
    at hudson.remoting.Command.readFrom(Command.java:126)
    at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:36)
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:63)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:77)
Slave JVM has not reported exit code. Is it still running?
[10/11/18 11:45:17] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[10/11/18 11:45:17] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

Comment: possibly off-topic and belonging to server-fault. In any way it might help if you include a config file from jenkins or any info how you configured your connection to your VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted on https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42856 this could be a known issue. Can you see if the below workaround mentioned on the above JENKINS bug helps ?

*I have a similar problem with the channel being terminated too early. I was able to circumvent it using the following SSH prefix and postfix commands:*

Prefix: `powershell -Command "cd C:\jenkins ; java -jar slave.jar" ; exit 0 ; rem '`

Postfix: `'`

Comment: @Pascal.S See below; 

prefix command 
 powershell -Command "cd C:\jenkins ; java -jar slave.jar" ; exit 0 ; rem

suffix command 
 ' 

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgeED.png

Comment: Try prefix start agent command - powershell -Command "cd C:\jenkins ; java -jar slave.jar" suffix start agent command - ''. I haven't tried this myself so not sure if those commands result in some syntax error but give it a try with different combinations and keep us posted

Comment: Good to know! Cheers